# How to generate reports using HtmlTestRunner for unittests which invlove xml-rpc communication?

Tags: python, unit-testing, xml-rpc

If it is a unittest that invlove a single xml-rpc requests/response between an xmlrpc client/server, it works fine and generates report on one end but if the scenario scales to more than one xmlrpc request, the report is not getting generated.

Here goes the code snippet template:

On one machine ABC I have,

```
class ABC():
          def add():
                .......
          def subtract():
                .......

class MachineABCTest(unittest.TestCase):
         def test_ABC(self):
               x1 = abc_client.multiply() #method which resides in MachineXYZTest
               y1 = abc_client.divide() #method which resides in MachineXYZTest

suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(MachineABCTest)
runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(stream=fp, verbosity=2)
runner.run(suite)

class ServerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.abc_server = SimpleThreadedXMLRPCServer(("XXX.XXX.XXX.1", 8000))
        self.abc_server.register_instance(ABC()) #methods add & subtract will get registered

    def run(self):
        self.moderator_srv.serve_forever()

abc_server = ServerThread()
abc_server.start()
```

---

And on the other machine,

```
class XYZ():
          def multiply():
                .......
          def divide():
                .......

class MachineXYZTest(unittest.TestCase):
         def test_XYZ(self):
              x2 = xyz_client.add() #method which resides in MachineXYZTest
              x2 = xyz_client.subtract() #method which resides in MachineXYZTest

suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(MachineXYZTest)
runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(stream=fp, verbosity=2)
runner.run(suite)

class ServerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.xyz_server = SimpleThreadedXMLRPCServer(("XXX.XXX.XXX.2", 8000))
        self.xyz_server.register_instance(XYZ()) # methods multiply & divide will get registered

    def run(self):
        self.xyz_server.serve_forever()

xyz_server = ServerThread()
xyz_server.start()
```

---

There's nothing wrong with the import statement as well

```
import HTMLTestRunner
reload(HTMLTestRunner)

dir = "D:\\Test\\ABC_XYZ_Test"
fp = file(os.path.join(dir, "TestResult.html"), "wb")
```

which I have included in both the files.

It would have generated report if there was only one call being made from ABC like

```
x1 = abc_client.multiply() #method which resides in MachineXYZTest
```

and xyz_server serving that request. In this case the report will be generated on the client end(here, ABC).

The problem occurs only if there's a 2-way communication occurring 'or' there are more than one request(as seen in the above code snippet) being made(from ABC to XYZ or vice-versa) .

Thanks.

Comment: This question looks totally incoherent to me.  Please rewrite your question more clearly.  Post the code that works and the code that fails.  Also, is this actually related to Sikuli?  You tagged as such, but don't mention it anywhere in the question.

Comment: @Nathaniel I'm sorry...I've now modified it. Hope it is clear now..I'm using Sikuli scripts in the unittests. That's why I tagged it though it's irrelevant in this question.

Comment: It's much improved, though I'm afraid I don't know enough to help, now that I understand what you're asking. When the code fails, exactly what happens? Is the report file empty? Does the code terminate, or does it hang? If you add print statements, does it execute either of the method calls?

Comment: Thanks...The test suite will run till the end in these cases and there is no crash/hang/termination as well. The only thing is that I get an empty report file.